# SQL Store nvarchar(max) from temp table to sql_variant

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, triggers, type-conversion

How can I check if a column in a temp table is nvarchar(max) and if so convert it or cast it to nvarchar(4000) so I can store it in sql_variant?
Here is the part of the code where @audit_oldvalue is sql_variant and @Item from #tempTrigT is nvarchar(max):

```
set @sql = 'select @audit_oldvalue=[' +@Item +'] from #tempTrigT';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql,N'@audit_oldvalue sql_variant OUTPUT',@audit_oldvalue OUTPUT
```

#tempTrigT:

```
Select * into #tempTrigT from (select * from deleted where @Action in ( 'U','D')) A UNION (select * from inserted where @Action ='I')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set @sql = 'set @audit_oldvalue=(select cast([' +@Item +'] as NVARCHAR(4000)) from #tempTrigT)';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql,N'@audit_oldvalue sql_variant OUTPUT',@audit_oldvalue OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the NVARCHAR(MAX) to NVARCHAR(4000) before casting to SQL_VARIANT.

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'test string';

SELECT CAST(@String AS SQL_VARIANT);                            --fail
SELECT CAST(CAST(@String AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS SQL_VARIANT);    -- success
```

Comment: Can you modify it to my code? because I cant. And also is it possible to first check if its NVARCHAR(MAX) and then do the casting otherwise keep it as is?